# Trying to get includes working with AsciiDoc Java Interface

Tags: java, groovy, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have to admit that I am new to AsciiDoc and ASciiDoctor...

What I am trying to accomplish is to render a given AsciiDoc template (https://github.com/masch70/arc42-template-asciidoc) with groovy. My solution is to make use of the AsciiDoctor Java Interface which seems to be a rewrite of AsciiDoc running with jRuby.
The code runs fine so far:

```
@Grab('org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-java-integration:0.1.4')
import org.asciidoctor.*
def asciidoctor = Asciidoctor.Factory.create()
def output = asciidoctor.renderFile(new File('index.ad'),[
'in_place':true,
'section-numbers':true,
'header_footer':true,
])
```

but it seems that it ignores the include sections which look pretty ok to me:

```
include::sections/02_architecture_constraints.ad[]
```

Instead of including the file, a link to the file gets rendered.

The AsciiDoctor manual says includes are supported: http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#include-directive , so the question is, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `safe` option as well. By default the `safe` option for API is `SECURE` or 20 (integer value) which disables `include` directives to be rendered. You can use any of the below key-value pair:

```
'safe':'SAFE'
'safe': 1

'safe':'SERVER'
'safe': 10

'safe':'UNSAFE' //If you want
'safe': 0
```

Below should work.

```
def output = asciidoctor.renderFile(new File('index.ad'),[
'in_place':true,
'header_footer':true,
'safe':'SAFE'
])
```

Refer [Running AsciiDoctor Securely](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#running-asciidoctor-securely) for more details.

**UPDATE**
`toc` and `section numbers` are attributes in CLI, so we just need to add required attributes to options.

Simplest way:

```
def output = asciidoctor.renderFile(new File('index.ad'),[
'in_place':true,
'header_footer':true,
'safe':'SAFE',
'attributes': [toc: true, numbered: true] //I suppose
])
```

But the above tightly couples with the underlying ascii doc implementations which we wanted to abstract in the first place. Asciidoctor provides useful Builder patterns to overcome this clutter.

```
import static org.asciidoctor.AttributesBuilder.attributes
import static org.asciidoctor.OptionsBuilder.options
import org.asciidoctor.Placement

Attributes attributes = attributes().tableOfContents(true)
                                    .tableOfContents2(Placement.LEFT)
                                    .sectionNumbers(true)
                                    .get()

Options options = options().inPlace(true)
                           .headerFooter(true)
                           .attributes(attributes)
                           .get()

def output = asciidoctor.renderFile(new File('index.ad'), options)
```

Visit this [package from asciidoctor java integration](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctorj/tree/master/src/main/java/org/asciidoctor) and it will be pretty much clear as to how things can be tailored easily.

Comment: great! that worked. Maybe you have another hint for the toc and section numbers? The `asciidoc` clie command call had the parameter `-a toc2` and `-n` - both I don't know how to translate in the correct way. `'section-numbers':true` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Yes, because they are attributes. Have a look at my update. @Ralf

Comment: Great. That was exactly the knowledge I was missing. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try the [asciidoctor gradle plugin](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin).

Comment: the asciidoctor gradle plugin is great, but in this case I wanted to avoid external dependencies. BTW: the plugin is one of those plugins where I don't know which benefits I get. The size of the code seems equal to me...